# How to solve meson setup dependency issue?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

Try install gtk-3.99.0 on CentOS. No root privilege.
`meson setup --prefix ${HOME}/TOOLS/gtk/3.99.0 /tmp/builddir`

```
Run-time dependency cairo-gobject found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

meson.build:353:0: ERROR: Dependency "cairo-gobject" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

Tried install cairo-gobject locally and get below files.

```
/local/cairo-gobject/usr/lib/libcairo-gobject.so.2
/local/cairo-gobject/usr/lib/libcairo-gobject.so.2.11512.0
/local/cairo-gobject/usr/lib64/libcairo-gobject.so.2
/local/cairo-gobject/usr/lib64/libcairo-gobject.so.2.11512.0
```

But meson still complain no cairo-gobject. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download cairo from https://www.cairographics.org/releases/
2. Install cairo.
3. `setenv PKG_CONFIG_PATH ${YOUR_PATH}/cairo/1.16.0/lib/pkgconfig`

> ```
> Run-time dependency cairo found: YES 1.16.0
> Run-time dependency cairo-gobject found: YES 1.16.0
> ```